# Upload ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile To Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

How can I upload a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` to Amazon S3?

```
@file_data = params[:upload][:file]
s3 = AWS::S3.new
obj = s3.buckets['WeMake'].objects.create("video", file)
```

I then get this error: ArgumentError (:data must be provided as a String, Pathname, File, or an object that responds to #read and #eof?):

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I needed to access the actual file, `params[:upload][:file].tempfile` and add a file extension to the s3 upload, `obj = s3.buckets['Bucket'].objects.create("video.mov", @file_data.tempfile)`.